# Query outputting data twice

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, echo

I have the following snippet:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users") or die(mysql_error());
echo "<table>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    foreach($row as $value)
    {
        echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
    }

    echo "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";?>
```

This snippet should, I think, output each piece of data from the table once.  The problem is, I get it twice.  So, for example

> me@email.com me@email.com Joe Joe Bloggs Bloggs

Why might it be doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) does both numeric and associative (`MYSQL_BOTH`), giving you two keys each.

If you want numeric keys, use

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_NUM))
```

if you want associative array, use:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

Note also, that the `mysql_*` functions are **deprecated** and you should use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: And a lesson was learned that day, thank you.  Will mark as correct when timer permits.

Answer (score 0):

change your code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
...
```

AND... mysql_* functions are deprecated, please consider moving to mysqli_* or PDO.

There, you will find possibilities to fetch one or all rows to an array...

- with numeric indices only
- with associative indices only
- with both (--> double output in your case)

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL Fetch Array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

The function by default uses `MYSQL_BOTH` which will give you an associative array along with a numbered array. For example:

Table:

```
name | emai
joe     joe@email.com
```

The array returned will have

```
$row{
    [0] = "joe",
    ['name'] = "joe",
    [1] = "joe@email.com",
    ['email'] = "joe@email.com",
    }
```

You will have to use `MYSQL_ASSOC` or `MYSQL_NUM` as the second argument

**NOTICE**: Do not use MySQL_* functions for they have been deprecated as of PHP 5.5. Use PDO or MySQLi_* instead